# Why is the tensor product of complex planes $\mathbb C$ again just $\mathbb C$?

Tags: tensor-products, quantum-mechanics

As the title says already, why does the following equality hold

\begin{equation}
   \bigotimes^N \mathbb C = \mathbb C
\end{equation}

My question comes from an example regarding the bosonic Fock space $\mathcal F_+$ over $\mathbb C$ and the harmonic oscillator where we had

\begin{equation}
  \mathcal F_+(\mathbb C) = \bigoplus\limits_{N = 0}^\infty \bigotimes\limits_{\text{sym}}^N \mathbb C = \bigoplus\limits_{N = 0}^\infty \mathbb C 
\end{equation}
My Professor said that tensorizing one dimensional spaces gives the space itself. I kind of get what is meant but not how this applies here. Thanks for any answere in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a basic fact (which you can find in every text on tensor products, for example [here](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/linmultialg/tensorprod.pdf)) that the tensor product of $K$-vector spaces $\otimes_K$ satisfies
$$K \otimes_K V \cong V$$
for every $K$-vector space $V$. The isomorphism is defined by using the [universal property of the tensor product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product#Universal_property) via the $K$-bilinear map $K \times V \to V$, $(a,v) \mapsto av$. Thus, it maps $a \otimes v \mapsto av$. The inverse map is $v \mapsto 1 \otimes v$.

In particular, we have $K \otimes_K K \otimes_K \cdots \otimes_K K \cong K$ for any finite number of copies of $K$. Notice that it is not precise to write equality here.